# Responsively scale css-animated logo made up of multiple, overlayed, different-sized images

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, overlay

So I'm having some trouble making a multi-image, overlayed, animated logo become responsive.

Here is a recreation of the logo: https://jsfiddle.net/vk0w42z6/

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now, and have tried everything I could. I've used CSS transforms, some html trickery, and it just doesn't seem to be working.

The main problem is that as the images are differently-sized, I can get the largest image to shrink using a simple

```
max-width:90vw;
```

but the smaller, overlayed images aren't scaling down.

So could someone please help me make this logo responsive?

Things I've tried:

- Make container relative, and all children absolute
- Some CSS display trickery.
- (will keep adding as people recommend things)

Comment: You're probably better off using SVG for that...simpler all round. In fact SVG is exactly what you need here,

Comment: you could scale the whole header -- https://jsfiddle.net/9hb8k8qb/

Comment: I'll be researching a solution for this through SVG, but in the meanwhile @Tasos 's solution worked pretty well. :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you absolutely need a HTML/CSS responsive logo only, I've managed to achieve this implementation as follows:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwf7c6pn/1/)

You can play around with percent values until satisfied. This should meet most of your needs.

P.S. I removed the animation for now because there was a lot of unnecessary CSS there interfering with this layout. You can implement it again.

HTML:

```
<body style="background-color:#1c1c1c;">
  <div style="width:100%;" >
    <div style="position: relative; max-width:800px; width: 100%;">

    <div id="compass">
                    <img alt=" compass-top " id="compass-top"
                class="compass-top " src="http://icanindia.org/go-sxse/medias/img/spoke-only-white.png "
                width="100%" > 

                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </div>


                    <img alt="base-2 "
                class="compass-bottom-2 " src=
                "http://icanindia.org/go-sxse/medias/img/sxse_logo_no_compass.png " style=
                "max-width: 800px; width:100%; height:auto; float:left;" >           
                 <div style="clear:both;"></div>         
                </div>

            </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#compass{
        width:20%;
        position:absolute;
        left:37%;
        background:url("http://icanindia.org/go-sxse/medias/img/back-only-white.png ");
        background-size:100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```